# axios.get dentro de un for

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api

Saludos amigos, estoy nuevo con Nodejs y tengo este problema, mi funcion recibe un array con unos ids de productos y necesito iterar sobre ese array para consultar y traer la imagen de ese producto y de este modo ir armando un array con los resultados y retornarlo.

```
function getImgProducts(line_items,cd){

let promises = [];  
for (let a = 0; a < line_items.length; a++) {
    promises.push(axios.get(Shopify.appurl+'products/'+line_items[a].product_id+'.json?published_status=any&fields=id,images'))
}

console.log(convertToStringValue(promises));
```

};

Podria alguien darme una guia con esto?

Comment: Usa `Promise.all()`

Comment: Que version de node estas usando? Para hacerlo mas sencillo puedes usar `async/await` pero necesitas minimo la version 7.6.0, Si tienes una version igual o mayor te escribo una respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma mas sencilla de resolver esto es utilizando `async/await`,
si no has escuchado o utilizado esto puedes leer [esta página](http://blog.builtbyedgar.com/funciones-asincronas-con-es7-async-await/).

Tomando tu código de ejemplo necesitas declarar `getImgProducts` como `async`:

```
   async function getImgProducts(line_items, cd) { ... }
// ^^^^^
```

Una vez hecho eso puedes utilizar tu `for` como si cualquier otra función síncrona.

```
async function getImgProducts(line_items,cd){

    let responses = [];  // Almacenamos todas las respuestas en un array

    try {
        for(let i = 0; i < line_items.length; i++) {
            let url = `${Shopify.appurl}products/${line_items[a].product_id}.json?published_status=any&fields=id,images`;
            responses.push(await axios.get(url));
            //             ^^^^^ importante añadir esta parte
        }
    } catch (err) {
        // En caso de algun error
    }

    return responses; // Retorna el array con las respuestas, cambialo como necesites

}
```

Solo recuerda que cuando una función es asíncrona, siempre se retorna una Promesa.

Ej:

```
function callerFunction() {
    getImgProducts().then(function(responses) {
        //           ^^^^ Utilizamos then para 
        // acceder a los datos una vez que ha sido resuelta.
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Garcias Gerardo, aprendiendo cosas nuevas con node..!!!

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente quedo asi:

```
async function getImgProducts(line_items){
    let responses = [];
    try {
        for(let i = 0; i < line_items.length; i++) {
            let url = `${Shopify.appurl}products/${line_items[i].product_id}.json`;
            responses.push(await axios.get(url));               
        }
    } 
    catch (err) {
    } 
    console.log('***************************responses', responses[0].data.product.image.src) ;
    return responses;
```

}

Y el llamado:

```
getImgProducts(line_items).then(function(imgsProducts) {....}
```